# know a usb device's endpoint

Tags: endpoint, libusb

Is there a bash command, a program or a libusb function (although I did not find one) which indicates me what are the OUT or IN endpoints of a usb device ?

For example, bNumEndpoints of libusb_interface_descriptor (from libusb1.0 library) shows me my usb drive has 3 endpoints, but how can I know what is their idnumber ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found the answer in lubusb-1.0. In was actually not a function, but a struct field :

> uint8_t libusb_endpoint_descriptor::bEndpointAddress
>
> The address of the endpoint described by this descriptor.
>
> Bits 0:3 are the endpoint number. Bits 4:6 are reserved. Bit 7
>   indicates direction, see libusb_endpoint_direction.

For each interface for the usb drive, I just had to write these lines to display the available endpoints :

```
cout<<"Number of endpoints: "<<(int)interdesc->bNumEndpoints<<endl;
for(int k=0; k<(int)interdesc->bNumEndpoints; k++) {
        epdesc = &interdesc->endpoint[k];
        cout<<"Descriptor Type: "<<(int)epdesc->bDescriptorType<<endl;
    cout<<"EP Address: "<<(int)epdesc->bEndpointAddress<<endl;
}
```

Where epdesc is the libusb_endpoint_descriptor and interdesc is the libusb_interface_descriptor.

Comment: Great code snippet/example, thank you! I hate the auto-generated docs like the one libusb has, it goes through every field of every structure, but no indication or example of how to obtain the structure in the first place.

Answer (score 14):

After you have claimed the device, run this (where $ represents the terminal entry point):

```
$ sudo lsusb -v -d 16c0:05df
```

Where 16c0:05df are your vendor and product ids separated by a colon. (If you don't know these, type lsusb and figure out which device is yours by unplugging and re-running lsusb)

If you get confused use the lsusb man page:

http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsusb

Then once your description comes up, find the line labeled bEndpointAddress and the hex code following will be the endpoint for that specific Report.